# $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \alpha)$ ( $\alpha = \sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})}$). Find the group isomorphic to $G(E/\mathbb{Q}) $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

$E$ is the splitting field of a $f(x)(\in\mathbb{Q}[x])$ whose degree is $8$. Say $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \alpha)$ (Here $\alpha = \sqrt{(2+\sqrt{2})(3+\sqrt{3})}$).
Find the group isomorphic to $G(E/\mathbb{Q}) $.

Let me show my solution. By tower theorem, $[E : \mathbb{Q}]=8$ (I could easily check the $deg$ $irr(\alpha, E_1) =2$ for  $E_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})).$ I found the all the element of $G(E/\mathbb{Q})$ like the below considering the roots of $irr(\alpha, E_1)$ are $\pm\alpha$

$\sigma(\in G(E/\mathbb{Q})) : \sqrt2 \to \pm \sqrt2, \sqrt3 \to \pm \sqrt3, \alpha \to \pm\alpha$

Therefore, $\forall \sigma(\in G(E/\mathbb{Q})), \vert \sigma \vert =2 $. Hence  $G(E/\mathbb{Q})\simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 $

Is my solution right? Aren't there any solutions except for mine?

Comment: Some of your maps $\sigma$ aren't valid field automorphisms.  For example, if $\sigma(\sqrt 2) = \sqrt 2$ but $\sigma(\sqrt 3) = -\sqrt 3$, then $\sigma$ needs to send $\alpha$ to one of the two square roots of $(2 + \sqrt 2)(3 - \sqrt 3)$, not to a square root of $(2 + \sqrt 2)(3 + \sqrt 3)$.

Comment: @RaviFernando, indeed! I didn't think that far

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. First show that the extension is Galois, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240921/mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt2-sqrt23-sqrt3-is-galois-over-mat?rq=1). Then consider the Galois group, compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298679/prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt2-sqrt23-sqrt3-is-galois-over-mathbb?noredirect=1&lq=1). Be careful, the claim $Q_8$ is not true there. But the answer points this out correctly.